# Vuejs + Vuetifyjs + v-text-field text-transform uppercase

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'am trying to add a v-text-input and I want the text in UPPERCASE ( in css: text-transform: uppercase ). I can't add a 'class', I can't add a 'style'. How do I do that? Things I tried:

```
 <v-text-field class="myUpperCase" v-model="dto" label="Username" required></v-text-field>
 <v-text-field style="text-transform: uppercase" v-model="dto" label="Username" required></v-text-field>
```

How do I achieve the uppercase on the text field? Thanks.
/Yore

Comment: should the v-model also only contain uppercase letters?

Comment: yes it must be, in fact. But I want visually UPPERCASE as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `v-text-field` wraps the input with other tags again and again. If you open the browser inspector, the structure will be like below:

```
<div class="v-input my-input v-text-field v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty">
  <div class="v-input__control">
    <div class="v-input__slot">
      <div class="v-text-field__slot"><input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-text-field__details">
      <div class="v-messages">
        <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you'd like to use css to reach the goal, you need to use css selector to apply your styles like `.my-input input`:

**PS:** In below sample, `class=my-input` is placed in top level, not at input element. Your second approach which uses `style="bla...bla.."` will be there also.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 'test abc'
  },
});
```

```css
.my-input input{
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.1.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<v-app id="app">
  <v-text-field class="my-input" :value="value">
  </v-text-field>
</v-app>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you very much my friend

Comment: Hey, I had a problem. The model does not follow the case set ;( . The final value is not uppercase as well. Is there something to do about it ?

Comment: @Yore because this transformation (text-transform: uppercase) is **purely visual**, it will not change the value of the input element. You have to manually convert it inside `@input` handler as other answers did. or you may prefer to use one computed property.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, it's not working on my side with Vuetify 2.2.27.

Comment: @DevonDahon make sure your CSS is not `scoped`, otherwise won't work

Answer (score 3):

Use the `toUpperCase()` function:

```
<input type="text" :value="name.toUpperCase()" @input="name = $event.target.value.toUpperCase()">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to use <input /> I want to use <v-text-input />. I use many other features of the tag, including rules, etc.. SO I can't change it.

Comment: @Yore well, see if it also works on <v-text-field> tag.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a `v-model` directive in the `<v-text-field>` component,  v-text-field does support a `v-model`, but you have more control if instead you use the `value` prop, which you can use as an `<input>` tag. After all a `v-model` is just a combination of `value` and an event. So all you have to do is use the `toUpperCase()` function. Therefore, the solution I picture is:

```
<v-text-field type="text" :value="dto.toUpperCase()" @input="dto = $event.target.value.toUpperCase()">
```

Comment: Hello, this was nice but I needed a CSS based solution. but thanks anyways

Comment: @alex `but v-text-field does not support a v-model` is not correct. `v-text-field` does support `v-model`. It has one prop=**value**, emit one event=**input** for `v-model`.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, i actually use v-model always, i'll edit the answer immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use the masks of the v-text-field. You can specify whatever you want, i.e. for license plates of Spain you can type: mask="####AAA" which will put any CHAR in Capital letters. More info here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#

Comment: [The mask prop and functionality has been removed.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#v-text-field)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the model to be Uppercase as well you can do a watch like this:

```
watch: {
  dto: function (val) {
     this.dto = val.toUpperCase();
  },
},
```

It worked for me, and seems simplier